# C# type corresponding to T-SQL's INT(32) (possibly NAN)

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, primary-key, int32

My C# manipulates ID's read from the Database. Originally, they are stored in **CHAR(32) NOT NULL** format. (that's the table's primary key)

Once in C#, this is converted to Int32 (logically ?)

But when I need to insert those values back into another table with a similar structure, but where the primary key's type is **INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL)**, I (logically) get the following error, as most CHAR(32) are not valid integers :

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store
>    in ID Column.  Expected type is
>   Int32.

Assuming that I want to keep the INT type for my target ID column, how should the C# code send the "E6802AA26C748A5A0EDE987384D2C48" to the SQL server for it not to complain that this is not a true Integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E6802AA26C748A5A0EDE987384D2C48 is not an Int32. It's a GUID. You'd need 128 bits to store it, not 32.